# Posting an answer after a question is closed and migrated?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, closed-questions

[This question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12240/why-2-distributions-can-not-be-multiplied?noredirect=1) was closed and migrated to Math.SE 20 minutes ago (as of this writing). User Marek posted an answer to this question 15 minutes ago. I thought question closure/migration locks the quesion from being answerable? How did that happen?

Comment: Interesting indeed; the revision history does not reveal anything, so this is a question to the team.

Comment: Marek's answer definitely wasn't there when I migrated... odd indeed.

Comment: Oh, thanks for asking this, I also wondered whatever happened to the answer. I started to write the answer before migration and clicked to post after the migration (I presume). Obviously I hit some rare usecase. But as the question was migrated (and so inapropriate for this site) I didn't bother investigating this further.

Answer (score 3):

Closing does not necessarily block the question from getting answered, in that the server will accept answers but the UI generally tries to discourage this. See here:

[Why was an answer allowed on a question that was merged into another one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79434/why-was-an-answer-allowed-on-a-question-that-was-merged-into-another-one)

Migration does, however, when the question is locked.